# SharePoint 2007 - editing Global Audiences

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, global, audience

This is a ridiculous question and I hate myself for having to ask.

I have an issue that some users from AD are not able to see some secure sections of a share-point site. the webpart is filtered by a 'global audience' list.

where do I need to go on share point 2007 to be able to see and amend this group information.
I have full admin rights to the server so its just an 'lack of knowledge' issue.

Many thanks,
Pierce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to the global audiences section of sharepoint you go to the audiences link in the audiences section of the shared services administration site.
That site is avilable from the Central administration site.

Reference: [google books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Gq6msp711YQC&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=how+to+add+people+to+a+global+audience+in+sharepoint&source=bl&ots=YbuJx1COJX&sig=od3yI0Pes_Y7M9HsA-qkrtAS8i8&hl=en&ei=DvlGTLOWIYKi0gTtr7G6BA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20add%20people%20to%20a%20global%20audience%20in%20sharepoint&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Audiences are not the same as security trimming. If the user in the non-secure audience finds the link to a "secured" page they can still access it, and most likely all pages will still show up in search etc.

See this link for more [SharePoint Audience Targeting vs. Item Level Security](http://blog.solanite.com/keith/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=11564265-6153-4557-aee2-72d1f62fa4c1&ID=9).

Comment: thanks Aidan, This is a web part linking to reporting services. So without the webpart there is no real way they will find their way across, as nothing else runs in sharepoint mode on the SSRS box. Good point if I was using this for pages on the site.